# AJAX mysql command not immediately executed?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

So I have some code, which checks for whether a one time use discount code exists, and if so, it applies it and then marks it as used in the database.  The problem is, it ends up being useable more than once if you spam click it, and then some time maybe 15-20 seconds later it stops being useable.

The relevant javascript component:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

      discountAmount += parseFloat(xmlhttp.responseText); 
      modifyCartOrder();
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","forms/jsPromoCode.php?code="+code+"&type="+order_name,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This is processed over in the php file, and when a match is found we echo that amount and then delete the entry

```
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM discounts_available WHERE `index`=$index");
```

The php file is indeed doing what its supposed to.  When you click apply code, it is immediately deleted from the database.  The problem is, even with the code no longer in the db, you can still apply the code over and over for some amount of time before the js file finally realises there is no entry in the db.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if it exists in DB then only you should proceed with  request, it  should be very first statement. 
If it does not exists you can send response saying code already applied.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to lock the table ASAP so no other instances can modify the table concurrently.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your problem, exactly I am assuming lost of things, so..

```
//this is triggered on some click, right?
//TODO:- check if button is disabled? you can have some js variable or check button attribute disbled
//TODO:-if its not disaled->{so first disable the button when it is clicked } else do nothing
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

      discountAmount += parseFloat(xmlhttp.responseText);
      // if succefull keep button disabled
      // else renable it, so that it can be clicked again. 
      modifyCartOrder();
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","forms/jsPromoCode.php?code="+code+"&type="+order_name,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

thers's no syntax problem here in your code its logical,
ajax call is asynchronous call, it does not happen in sequence
1) You clicked
2) Request Sent
3) Request Processed
4) JS is informed : your modifyCartOrder function executed

what I am trying to say here is that,  there is no 3 immediately after 2, 3 will take time to start, js has no control over it, whenever php is done it will reply there's no guarantee. so you can repeat 1 again and again, and 2 will keep repeating... and so 3 will... 
I hope I understood your problem, and you understood what I am trying to say :)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is :** You are sending **asynchronous ajax calls** from following code :

> xmlhttp.open("GET","forms/jsPromoCode.php?code="+code+"&type="+order_name,**true**);

**Solution :** as defined , for opening an ajax call , method is :

> **xmlhttp.open(method,url,async)**

So, You have to modify above line as:

> xmlhttp.open("GET","forms/jsPromoCode.php?code="+code+"&type="+order_name,**false**);